# Taking a specific element from a csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Trying to get a specific entry in csr_array, ex. a[r, c] returns an array rather than a scalar. What should I do to get the scalar?

If I take float(a[r, c]), the single element array is returned correctly (as a scalar), yet seems a bug?

WKR,
Oren

Comment: There's a bug in recent scipy versions in `csr` indexing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174166/what-is-the-use-case-of-numpy-array-of-scalar-value